# Unable to unmarshal LocalDate and LocalTime class using Jackson

Tags: java, json, akka, unmarshalling, akka-http

I'm making a POST route using akka, where I'm deserializing my Json data into Video object, but the following curl request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title": "Video Title","videoDate":"10-2-2018","videoTime":"12:10:11"}' http://localhost:9090/updatedData
```

gives an error: `Cannot unmarshal JSON as Video`

The request works fine when I remove videoDate and videoTime fields from json.

`Jackson.unmarshaller(VideoInfo.class)`

```java
//Video.class
public class Video {
    private String title;
    private LocalDate videoDate;
    private LocalTime videoTime;
}
```

The maven dependency used is

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's my route /updatedData

```java
post(() ->
      path("updatedData", () -> {
          LOGGER.info("calling POST /updatedData");
          return entity(Jackson.unmarshaller(Video.class), videoInfo -> {
              LOGGER.debug("Payload received : " + videoInfo.toString());
              ArrayList<HttpHeader> headers = getCORSHeaders();
              return respondWithHeaders(headers, () ->
                                        onSuccess(videoFrameProcessing.updateVideoInfo(videoInfo), this::complete));
                            });
                        })),
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, also which Jackson dependencies do you use (support for LocalDate and LocalTime requires the jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependency)

Comment: The ISO format for LocalDate would be `2018-02-10` (if the 2 is the month in your example).

Comment: See answer, you need to add that Java 8 Time API module. Also the format might be a problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm getting the error information by making the curl request on the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson requires an additional [module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) for the Java 8 `Time` API.
The module

```
jackson-datatype-jsr310
```

has been **deprecated** and is now part of

```
jackson-modules-java8
```

---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Which means you need to register that module manually

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

---

The Akka `Jackson` class offers an overloaded version of `unmarshaller`, which you can use to pass a customized version of `ObjectMapper`

```
public static <T> Unmarshaller<HttpEntity, T> unmarshaller(ObjectMapper mapper, Class<T> expectedType) {
  return Unmarshaller.forMediaType(MediaTypes.APPLICATION_JSON, Unmarshaller.entityToString())
                     .thenApply(s -> fromJSON(mapper, s, expectedType));
}
```

So, instead of

```
Jackson.unmarshaller(Video.class)
```

use

```
Jackson.unmarshaller(objectMapper, Video.class);
```

The `objectMapper` parameter is the custom `ObjectMapper`

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

---

The complete snippet would be

```
post(() ->
   path("updatedData", () -> {
      LOGGER.info("calling POST /updatedData");

      final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

      return entity(Jackson.unmarshaller(objectMapper, Video.class), videoInfo -> {
          LOGGER.debug("Payload received : " + videoInfo.toString());
          ArrayList<HttpHeader> headers = getCORSHeaders();
          return respondWithHeaders(headers, () ->
                       onSuccess(videoFrameProcessing.updateVideoInfo(videoInfo), this::complete));
     });
 })),
```

Obviously, extract the `ObjectMapper` as a "global" variable.

Comment: I wasn't using any object mapper before. Please tell me how to proceed with object mapper as I'm just a beginner performing unmarshalling.

Comment: @Yatharth7 can you post the code which deserializes the response? Or is it just a CURL call?

Comment: Its just a curl call.

Comment: @Yatharth7 and what's that "Jackson.unmarshaller(VideoInfo.class)" in your question?

Comment: That's the route, I've added that in question now

Comment: Where should I provide ObjectMapper